# Save data from a field that contains json into another field of the database

Tags: mysql, sql, json, regex

I have a **MySQL** database which has two fields. The first field is named `postValues` and the other one is named `username`. The username is `null` to all records of my database.

Inside the field `postValues` there is a JSON string.
In this JSON string there might be a key `username`.

```
{
    otherfields,
    "username": "George",
    otherfields
}
```

There is also a chance that the `username` does not exist.

I need with an `SQL` query to check every record of the database if the key `username` exists inside the JSON string and if it exists save it to the same record at field `username`. Notice that the `otherfields` are not the same to every record and also the key `username` might not be in the same position to take the substr from the JSON string. I guess I need a regexp here.

Can anyone guide me.

Comment: Use any scripting language to achieve this. First read the postValue from database and json_decode it and get the username key from it and check the username exist in database, insert it else update it

Comment: My suggestion is to fix the future before you fix the past.  In other words, start by fixing the application that is sending you the data.  Then you only have to do the update once.

Comment: @TamilSelvan I am already doing this but it is taking too long and I might need to do this several times for testing before going live. So I thought that there might be a faster way.

Comment: Oh, this is testing.  Excellent.  Fix the application sending you the data so that it parses out the username before the record is inserted.

Comment: @DanBracuk please... this is not an option. There are several applications sending data which are external applications and can't be updated. This is an application which is live but I need to do tests to test databases before updating the live one. The value is going to be saved directly from now. For various reasons there are tests that I have to take over and over and this procedure takes a lot of time. I was hoping there is a query that could save me some time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use mysql to determine if the value exists, after all JSON data is just a string. So as long as you know the structure of the string you can get it.

Here's an example using REGEXP but you could also use LIKE.

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN `postValues` REGEXP '"username":"([a-zA-Z0-9]+)"' THEN 'YES' ELSE 'NO' END) AS `hasUserName` FROM `table`;
```

You could also use mysql to do the update to add the name to the other column. This gets really complicated really quickly but it works. Tested with `{"bla":123,"username":"Goerge","more":"abc"}`

```
UPDATE `table` SET `username`=(
  CASE WHEN `postValues` REGEXP '"username":"([a-zA-Z0-9]+)"' THEN
    (SUBSTRING_INDEX(REPLACE(REPLACE(`postValues`,SUBSTRING_INDEX(`postValues`,'"username":"',1),''), '"username":"', ''), '"', 1))
  ELSE NULL END
);
```